# Concatenate dataframes of different shapes on columns without reindexing or loosing index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 37 data frames of different shapes, I need to concatenate them. The following is what I tried:

```
path           = '/Users/data_frames/data'
all_files      = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in os.listdir(path) if i.endswith('pc.tsv')]
main           = []
for files in all_files:
    dfs = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(files, sep="\t")
    dfs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    main.append(pc_matrix)
merged_pr_matrix =pd.concat(main,axis=1)
```

The above script runs with this line,

```
dfs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

However, I lost the original index values (row names). I would like to keep them. For example, now I have the final matrix after concatenating, as following:

```
  ABV   TCG FGH HKL MK  MYT JUJN    MTPTA
0   5130132,5   22778,703125    675790,6875 4846942,5   106934,4453125  2884897,25  2777415 3487836
1   3478507,5   898987,375  2825588,5   5006338,5   119250,765625   4393944,5   3111324,25  2594582,75
2   18402,615234375 56879,6484375   524456,3125 323671,4063 166333,4375 78539,921875    233480,0625 35772,69140625
3   2310551,5   587836,1875 241836,5    5488325 29411,296875    517361,46875    190795,078125   67885,640625
4   95646,140625    1106308 1356453 17681780    592893,9375 1857957 1224196 1417179,25
```

In the original inputs I had values in index which I would like to keep.

Comment: if you want to keep them then change `drop=False`

Comment: can you post an example of two dfs that you are trying to merge?

Comment: You told pandas to drop the index by passing `drop=True` to `reset_index`. If you want to keep the index... don't drop them.